# java.lang.AssertionError at startapp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, startapp

I was trying to fix in my project, but I could not figure out how.
Everything went well during development, but after sharing to store and download it as this error occurred.
It makes me mad. Who can help me how to fix this ?. please. thanks so much!

This is my error :

[image: Stacktrace]

Report on store :

[image: Report on store]

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Just remove .idea files from project. And import project again. And Go to: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and select Invalidate and Restart and reupload project

Comment: I did so but has not been.

Answer (score 0):

my code on FirstActivity class

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageButton btnStart, btnMoreApp;
    private AdView adView;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    StartAppAd startAppAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_first);
    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //ad startApp
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "106697618", "200046203", true);
    /** Create Splash Ad **/
    StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState,
            new SplashConfig()
                    .setTheme(SplashConfig.Theme.GLOOMY)
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setAppName("Photo Frame")
    );

    btnStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btnMoreApp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_more_app);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMoreApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

...

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```